# ¿Cuál es el origen de los nombres de los números?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología

¿De dónde vienen las palabras para nombrar a los números?

En especial estoy interesado en el origen de las palabras 'once', 'doce', 'trece', 'catorce' y 'quince'.

Usamos un sistema numérico de base 10, ¿por qué estas palabras existen pero luego utilizamos las compuestas dieciséis (diez + seis), diecisiete (diez + siete), etc.?

Me parece muy curioso que en francés usen vocablos similares pero luego en 16 no digan dix-six sino seize. Es decir, es como si tuvieran una palabra más que nosotros en este sentido.

Comment: Vienen del latín, claro, y por lo que veo, en latín sí que tienen sentido. Once por ejemplo es "undecim", se ve de donce sale la palabra "once", y además se ve que coge la idea de "diez y uno". Sin embargo, date cuenta de que el sistema decimal no se adoptó en Europa hasta la Edad Media, por entonces se usaban los números romanos. 18 por ejemplo es "duodeviginti", que supongo que será algo como "veinte menos dos".

Comment: @JoulSauron Pamplinas! Como sabe cualquier chileno de ley ["once" significa  "aguardiente"](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?once) :)

Comment: @JoulSauron ¿No te parece que deberías poner tu comentario como respuesta?

Comment: @belisarius ONCE es la Organización Nacional de Ciegos de España, como todo el mundo sabe :P

Comment: @deStrangis La quiero elaborar un poco más, cuando tenga algo de tiempo la paso como respuesta.

Comment: Da una ojeada a esta [respuesta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9811/707).

Answer (score 13):

Muy buena pregunta. He estado buscando, insuficiente como para considerarlo un comentario pero suficiente como para discutirla.

Según la RAE vemos cual es el origen de la adopción de diez signos

> Existen dos sistemas básicos para representar los números mediante signos: la «numeración arábiga», llamada así porque fue introducida en Occidente por los árabes, y la «numeración romana», heredada de los romanos. Además, los números pueden representarse mediante palabras, denominadas «numerales». En la numeración arábiga, cualquier número puede representarse mediante la combinación de solo diez signos, llamados cifras o dígitos: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9; la numeración romana se basa en el empleo de siete letras del alfabeto latino, a las que corresponde un valor numérico fijo. Debido a su mayor simplicidad, la numeración arábiga sustituyó en la Edad Media al sistema romano.

[Fuente: RAE](http://www.rae.es/dpd/?key=n%C3%BAmeros)

Para 'once', 'doce', 'trece', 'catorce' y 'quince' como bien menciona JoulSauron el once proviene de "undecim", como podemos ver en la tabla de [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aLatin_cardinal_numbers)

El que pararan en el quince y en francés haya 16 es por razones históricas, como responde un usuario a una [pregunta similar](http://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070525120408AANyxdx):

**"***Trataron de ponerle nombres propios a cada número: once, doce, trece, catorce, quince, pero a partir de entonces decidieron que no valía la pena darle un nombre a cada uno de ellos, así que surge la regla dieciséis, diecisiete.
Además eso pasó en todos los idiomas: eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, aquí eso pasó sólo hasta el doce y después surge la regla.*

En francés: onze, douze, treize, quatorze, quinze, seize, dix-sept, dix-huit.
Aquí llegó hasta el dieciséis y luego la regla.

El Italiano: undici, dodici, tredici, quattordici, quindici, sedici, diciassette y diciotto, también hasta el dieciséis y luego la regla.

En alemán solo el once y el doce: elf, zwölf, dreizehn, vierzehn. fünfzehn, sechzehn, siebzehn y achtzehn y luego la regla.

En portugués: onze, doze, treze, quatorze, quinze, dezesseis, dezessete y dezoito
hasta el quince igual que en español.

En griego: solo el once y el doce: ένδεκα, δώδεκα, δέκα τρία, δεκατέσσερα, δεκαπέντε, δέκα έξι, δεκαεπτά y δεκαοχτώ

Como puedes ver simplemente trataron de darle nombre a los números siguientes al diez y después aprendieron que era mejor una regla, pero ya se llamaban así y  así se quedaron.**"**

**Añado en catalán, hasta el 16 y luego la regla: onze, dotze, tretze, catorze, quinze, setze, disset, divuit, dinou.

No hay un número tope al que todos se ciñeran porque muchos venían de la numeración romana sino de cómo cada zona adopto la nueva numeración poniéndoles nombres propios.

En el caso del español los nombres se asemejan al latín hasta el 12:

Latín -> Español

- unus -> uno
- duo -> dos
- tres ->tres
- quattuor -> cuatro
- quinque -> cinco
- sex -> seis
- septem -> siete
- octo -> ocho
- novem ->nueve
- decem --> diez

Hasta el 15 se abrevian:

- undecim --> (un+dece) -> abreviado a once
- duodecim --> (duo+dece) -> abreviado a doce
- tredecim --> (tres+dece) trece
- quattordecim --> (quattor+dece) --> catorce
- quindecim -->(quinque+dece) quince

Fíjate que los ordinales si que se asemejan: (decem) décimo, undécimo, duodécimo, y hasta el 19 cambian el decem/décimo a prefijo -> decimoquinto, decimosexto, decimoséptimo, decimoctavo, decimonoveno.

[Fuente:enciclopedia](http://enciclopedia.us.es/index.php/N%C3%BAmero_ordinal)

Comment: Esto está muy bien, sin embargo no responde del todo a mi pregunta.

Por ejemplo en inglés 'eleven' viene de 'ein lifon' que significa diez + uno, y 'twelve' de 'twe lif' (dos + diez).

¿Qué pasó en español? ¿Cuáles son esas razones históricas?

Comment: Editado. Sin embargo y porque no soy historiador, matemático ni profesor esperaría la aceptación de algún usuario que domine alguna de las materias.

Comment: No "pasó" nada en español, simplemente se adaptó fonéticamente lo que se venía diciendo para cada número en latín, lo mismo que en el resto de lenguas romances.