# What is the relation between "quince" and "cinco"?

Tags: etimología, números

I am learning now the [numbers in Spanish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27KsV2MUKGU), but I would like to understand something.
When I see the numbers names between 11-19 in Spanish, then I've noticed that is a portmanteau of the number plus the suffix "ce".

For example:

- *Once* is 11, because it is *uno* + the suffix "ce".
- *Doce* = 12 (*doce* + "ce")
- *Trece* = 13 (*tres* + "ce")
- *Catorce* = 14 (*cuatro* + "ce")

But when we come to number **15**, unlike the previous numbers, then I don't find the explanation of the relation between ***cinco*** and the name ***quince***. What is the explanation for that?

[image]

Comment: Spanish has no such word as **sinco*, only *cinco*. This would make more sense if you were learning a [non-seseante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seseo) dialect, since then [sinco] and [θinco] would sound nothing like each other, and therefore you would not make spelling mistakes. [See here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI) for transcription symbols.

Comment: Note that there's also *sece* (very old fashioned) for 16 as well. But the /k(w)i/ transition to Spanish was irregular, at times maintaining /k/ (*quince, quinientos*), and at others softening to /θ/~/s/ (*cinco, cincuenta*), even with a similar root

Comment: Related, but in Spanish: [¿Cuál es el origen de los nombres de los números?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3969/12637).

Comment: On a related note, does anybody know why *cuatro* /kw/- but *catorce* /k-/ and *cinco* /s/- but *quince* /k/-? I mean Latin /kw/- almost regularly changed to /k/ except before /a/, and then /k/ changed to /ts/ before front vowels. It looks as if both *catorce* and *quince* are exceptions, but *catorce* is an exception of an exception!

Answer (score 3):

*Cinco* comes from the Latin *quinque* and *cuatro* comes from the Latin *quattuor*.

Over time the spelling follows the general pronunciation, and you get modifications as you mentioned.

Comment: He may not be aware that *cinco* follows the pronunciation, given how he’s spelled it.

Comment: Therefore 5° == **quin**to