# ¿Por qué 21 va junto pero 31 va separado?

Tags: números

¿Hay alguna razón por la que los números del 21 al 29 se escriben en una sola palabra a diferencia de los números a partir del 31?

Comment: Quizá porque no dices "veinte y nueve" sino "veintinueve". Por el contrario dices "treinta y uno" (dos palabras unidas por la conjunción _y_). Entiendo que para 16 al 19 (que son los realmente raros), la forma "diez y seis" en algún momento pasó a pronunciarse distinto y de ahí a adquirir la grafía "dieciséis" (no _diezyseis_). Creo que la clave a la respuesta de esta pregunta está en qué les pasó a los números 16 -19. A partir de 30, es claro que todos son dos palabras unidad por la conjunción. [¿Cuál es el origen de los nombres de los números?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3969/5481)

Answer (score 4):

Ambos grupos de números se pueden escribir en una o tres palabras:

> *veintidós* o *veinte y dos*
>   *treintaidós* o *treinta y dos*
>   *noventaicinco* o *noventa y cinco*

Hay una clara preferencia en el mundo hispanohablante por las formas univerbales para 21-29, y por las triverbales para más de 30.  No obstante, son válidas, y reconocidas en la Ortografía de 2010.

La decisión de escribir en una o tres palabras radica en la pronunciación.  Cada palabra en castellano admite como máximo una sílaba acentuada (algunas carecen de ellas por completo).  Así, al decir, *veinte y cuatro*, tenemos dos sílabas acentuadas (*y* carece de acuentación), efectivamente *véinte y cuátro*.  Pero con el paso de tiempo, mucha gente empezó a pronunciar estas palabras con una sola sílaba acentuada, es decir, *veinte y cuátro*. Perdido el primer acento, en la lengua oral, efectivamente es una palabra.  Y en la escrita, estas palabras se escriben juntas.

También, otra cosa que ayudó a que las formas de 21-29 se uniesen de forma más extendida y temprana es que *veinte* termina en *e*, que es una vocal intermedia anterior, y bastante cerca a una *i*, que es una vocal cerrada y anterior.  Estas se juntan más fácilmente que una *a* (abierta y central) con la *i*.

Comment: Pregunté sobre un artista asturiano que canta en asturianu en algunas canciones. Rodrigo Cuevas se llama, muy recomendable.